# C# Autocomplete, how to disable custom text?

Tags: c#, winforms

**Goal:**

I have a working autocomplete set for a text box. Currently, data source is SQL server.

If I type any letter within the text box, some data will suggest and append to text box.

But, how can I prevent the user to use custom text? But only use data what is suggested in the Auto Complete?

**Code:**

```
customer.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
customer.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
customer.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autotext;
```

Comment: Would a drop-down control work better at this point to force only values from the data source?  Drop Down List option: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.comboboxstyle?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

From the Microsoft docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode?view=netcore-3.1

It looks like AutoCompleteMode is the ticket. If you set the mode to "Suggest" it "Displays the auxiliary drop-down list associated with the edit control. This drop-down is populated with one or more suggested completion strings."

There is even an example on the same webpage.

Comment: Setting it to Suggest does not work. I can still type custom text